# Determine the equation of a a plane tangent at a hyperboloid of one sheet in a point M. Prove that this tangent plane cuts the surface after two lines

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, surfaces

Determine the equation of a plane tangent at a hyperboloid of one sheet
$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}-\frac{z^2}{1}=1$
in a point M (2,3,1) . Prove that this tangent plane cuts the surface after two lines and find the angle between these two lines.

I was able to find the equation of the tangent plane by plugging in the coordinates of M:

$\frac{2x}{4}+\frac{3y}{9}-\frac{z}{1}=1$

which is equal to

$3x+4y-6z-6=0$

From here how can I prove that this plane cuts the surface after two lines?

Thank you a lot for any help given! I really appreciate it, because I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistake in those computations. Actually, the tangent plane is the plane$$x+\frac{2y}3-2z=2.$$And if you intersect this plane with the hyperboloid, you get the lines$$x=2\wedge y=3z\quad\text{and}\quad x=2z\wedge y=3.$$

Comment: You are right about the tangent plane, thank you! Can you expand a bit on how you get the lines please?

Comment: @aneys Plug in value of $z$ from the equation of plane into equation of hyperboloid. It results in $(x-2)(y-3) = 0$. Plug in $x = 2$ in equation of plane and that gives you $y = 3z$. So one of the lines is $x = 2, y = 3z$. You can plug it into equation of hyperboloid to confirm it is on the hyperboloid. Do the same for $y = 3$.

Comment: So  $\frac{x^{2}}{4} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} - z^{2} - 1=0$  <=> $9x^2 +4y^2 -36z^2 - 36=0$ is the equation of the hyperboloid. Z from the equation of the plane is $z=x/2 + y/3 -1$.

Plugging it in we have  $\frac{x^{2}}{4} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} - (x/2 + y/3 -1)^{2} - 1=0$ 

<=>  $\frac{x^{2}}{4} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} - \frac{xy-2y}{3} -  \frac{x^{2}}{4} + \frac{y^{2}}{9} +x - 1 -1=0$

<=> $ - \frac{xy-2y}{3} +x -2=0$
<=> $ -xy+2y+3x-6=0$
<=> $(x-2)(y-3)=0$
x=2 so $6+2y-6z-6=0$ => $y=3z$. You are right! Thank you!!  Now that I have the lines how do I find the angle between them?@MathLover

Comment: @aneys You know the direction vectors of both lines, right? So use formula $a \cdot b = |a| \ |b| \cos\theta$.

Comment: Thank you! The direction vector of the first line (a) is (0,3,1) and the direction vector of the second (b) line is (2,0,1). So we have $a \cdot b = 1$ . And $|a| = sqrt(10)$ and $|b|=sqrt(5)$ . So $\cos\theta = \frac{1}{5sqrt(2)}$. Is this alright? @MathLover

Comment: @aneys yes that is correct.

Comment: I went offline right after posting my answer, but I see that @MathLover helped you here. Is everyting clear now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think so, yes! Thank you a lot! I just expected the value of θ to be a more beautiful value (like 30,60,45,90 degrees). Can you also confirm I calculated its value correctly?

Comment: I undertand that, but no. That angle is about $81.87^\circ$, or $1.43$ radians.

Comment: @aneys if it partially meets your expectation, the value of $\tan \theta$ is simply $7$ :) :) I also think if you are satisfied with the answer after all the explanations, you should go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Alright, extremely many thanks to both of you for helping me! @MathLover